# binding function to different events that take parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 eventlisteners that are triggering two functions. However I think it should be possible to let them trigger the same function instead.

The eventlisteners are listening for keystrokes and the mousewheel.

```
$(document).mousewheel(onMouseWheel);

function onMouseWheel(event,delta)
{
  if(delta<0){
  code...
  }
  else if(delta>0){
  code...
  }
}
```

---

```
$(document).keydown(onKeyDown);

function onKeyDown(e)
{
   if (e.keyCode == 37){
   code...
   } 
   else if (e.keyCode == 39){
   code...
   }
}
```

Is it possible to combine these two, so I only have one function?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do it like this instead:

```
function onMouseWheel(event,delta) {
    if(delta<0){
        detectDown();
    } else if(delta>0){
        detectUp();
    }
}

function onKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37){
        detectDown();
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39){
        detectUp();
    }
}
```

since keydown and wheel events are so different. I'm guessing you want to combine these functiond; `detectDown` is the same for both the keydown and wheel event. Doing it like this captures that intention.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will probably do that. But what I actually want is to combine OnMouseWheel with onKeyDown, so they are only one function. It might be a bad idea though?

Comment: I don't see the point of doing that. You will still have these 4 if-statements.

Comment: I could have an if(e.keyCode == 37 || delta<0). The reason is to simplify and minimize amount of code.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but I don't see the point. You gain very little from these kinds of optimizations. Just think about the practical aspects: what would you name a function like this? `mouseWheelAndKeyDownListener`? That doesn't sound right. What if you also wanted to listen to `scrollDown`? What if you also want to detect numpad-keydown when numlock is off? This would make your function too complex.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for answering my question! Just want to do it the right way :)